# Source of the Yiddish word Cholent

Tags: food, shabbat, words, yiddish

Does anyone know what is the source of the Yiddish word Cholent?

Comment: the word is not yiddish, it is french

Comment: @user5535 It's definitely Yiddish (and not [currently] French, as far as I know)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholent#Etymology):

> Max Weinreich traces the etymology of
>   cholent to the Latin present
>   participle *calentem,* meaning "that
>   which is hot" (as in calorie), via Old
>   French *chalant* (present participle of
>   chalt, from the verb chaloir, "to
>   warm"). One widely quoted folk
>   etymology, relying on the French
>   pronunciation of cholent or the
>   Central and Western European variants
>   shalent or shalet, derives the word
>   from French *chaud* ("hot") and *lent*
>   ("slow"). Another folk etymology
>   derives cholent (or sholen) from the
>   Hebrew *she’lan,* which means "that
>   rested [overnight]". This refers to
>   the old time cooking process of Jewish
>   families placing their individual pots
>   of cholent into the town baker's ovens
>   that always stayed hot and slow-cooked
>   the food overnight.

Answer (score 6):

Someone I know insists it's abbreviated from the English *chow left overnight*. (I'm *almost* sure he's kidding.)

Answer (score 6):

The [Chaim SheYesh Bohem](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48000&st=&pgnum=122) mentions in the name of the Or Zarua that it comes from ״צלי-לן״ = ״צלנט״ that the food rested on the fire overnight.

Answer (score 4):

There is an old British myth (e.g. not true) that it comes from 'shule end' since the children were sent to retrieve the cholent pot from the communal cooking ovens after the end of synagogue services. 
*The Book of Jewish Food* by Claudia Roden, page 146

Answer (score 2):

According to my research, it is likely derived from the French word chalant, as mentioned in Dave's answer. I once taught a Cholent workshop, which included a history of both the food and the word. It was a really fun class; about 50% involved making and tasting Cholent.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I always thought that chaud lent (hot and slow in French) made the most sense.

Sefardim call their overnight slow-cooked stew "Chamin", which derives from "Cham" - Hebrew for hot.

In any case, all of the funny explanations of the word make me think that the root of it can't be Hebrew.

Comment: Did you mean this to be a comment on Dave's answer? Or on Gershon Gold's? Or on the question? It doesn't look like it was meant to be posted as an answer.

Comment: It would have been a meatier (pun intended) answer, if there were not several other good answers posted above.